# Scp from Linux to windows using freeSSHd

Tags: linux, windows-8, scp, freesshd

I need to run a script on my linux machine to be able to run a few commands on my windows server VM. One of these commands include scp and am having some difficulty with it.

I have installed freeSSHd on my windows machine which helps me give SSH access. I should be able to scp when there ssh running right? I also have WinScp installed on the windows VM. When I try and scp I get the following output,

```
$ scp runIOmeter.bat perf@<window's server ip>:C:\Users\perf\Documents
FIPS mode initialized
perf@<window's server ip>'s password:
runIOmeter.bat                                      100%  116   477.5KB/s   00:00
```

But when I check C:\Users\perf\Documents on the windows server, the file does not appear there. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Do not use freeSSHd, it's a crap software. Consider using some more robust solution, like Win32-OpenSSH (open source) or Bitvise SSH server (free for personal use).

Answer (score 0):

The backslash characters in 'C:\Users\perf\Documents' are interpreted in linux shell which should lead to "C:UsersperfDocuments". Try with C:\Users\perf\Documents. 
(assuming that freesshd or whatever software will actually interpret windows style path).

Answer (score 0):

Go to freesshd SFTP tab. There is your home path setting, and I think you will find your runIOmeter.bat under this path.